# Many values in the dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, regression, artificial-intelligence, image-preprocessing

I have some questions about how to deal with 0 value in 2d array.
I am planning to work on regression 1d CNN, but most of the data is made of 0.
I would like to replace this 0 to other small values such as 0.000001 simply because, if I put 0, regression process would not take into account the dataset values and find what is optimized model for my data set.
I have some instinct but, I need to prove it by referencing.
Would you be kind enough as to recommend me some references or any idea of this?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: If using pandas, you could fill all zero value with the mean and this can cancel out any bias.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to jitter your data by adding `0.0001 * numpy.raodom.randn(*your array shape*)` to your data. Whether it will help you in your specific problem, no one can tell, of course.

Comment: i can replace it. but do you have some reference of why we are doing this?